# How save form of form builder to database

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

I use [form builder](https://github.com/meysampg/yii2-formbuilder) **extension**, it's easy to create form in this extension, but I don't know how do I have to save the form in database.

for more information to understand:
look this [form builder extension](https://packagist.org/packages/pceuropa/yii2-forms). in this extension you have to create database using by migration, then you can create any form you want, after submit your custom form, it will create your form in data base.

ok, lets go to my problem. in this [extension](https://github.com/meysampg/yii2-formbuilder) that I use I have't seen any migration or something that create database for forms.

please compare both extension before answer. thanks a lot.

please help me if you can. thank a lot.

Comment: You should start from reading documentation: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-forms

Comment: @rob006 if I read this, can I save the form in database? I mean is it possible to save form like this?

Comment: @rob006 this link is regular form building . did you see the extesion?

Comment: Try to code something, you can save the form data in you db using your related controller and model.

Answer (score 0):

It is same as you save data in simple forms.

```
if ($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: it's different, did you see the estension?

Answer (score 0):

First, the model is based in your table of database. Example, in table product will need product model (`app/models/Product.php`). the attributes of the table are in the model.  Second, the controller class describe actions of this model (`app/controllers/ProductController.php`). For example, actionCreate, actionUpdate, actionDelete, using $model->save() to save data in action function. Third, in this case the view (`app/views/<name of model>/form.php`) generated in form builder, development codes using `$model` attributes, so that's present code development in HTML formats, but encapsulated within ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'your-form']). See more in  https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-forms

Comment: I updated my question to understand well. help me if it possible.